# How retrieve value from string collections in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, collections

I have a collection defined by:

```
public class CompanyModel
{
    public string compnName { get; set; }
    public string compnAddress { get; set; }
    public string compnKeyProcesses { get; set; }
    public string compnStandards { get; set; }
}
```

Then I stored names and addresses to this collection from a data table:

```
List<CompanyModel> companies = new List<CompanyModel>();
for(int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    companies.Add(new CompanyModel 
    { 
        compnName =  dt.Rows[i]["companyName"].ToString(),
        compnAddress =  dt.Rows[i]["address"].ToString()
    });
}
```

My question is how could I retrieve each compnName from that collection ?
I tried this

```
foreach (CompanyModel company in companies)
{
    string compnyName = company.compnName;
```

But it return me blank result.

Comment: How are you supposed to get each company names in a single string ? Do you want to concat them all ? What is the expected output ?

Comment: Do you mean I better declare compnName as string array ?

Comment: I can't tell that for you. You're the one who should tell us the expected output.

Comment: The output of dt is a table 1 column with many rows of different names. Then it will fill inside compnName. My purpose is to get this name one by one, so I can change the declaration of compnName if that is more suitalbe.

Comment: Expected output is each company Name that I put in compnName in the for loop

Comment: Then your code should be working (even if using LINQ would be recommended). Did you make sure `dt.Rows[i]["companyName"].ToString()` doesn't return an empty string ?

Comment: Yes, I am very sure! I can print them on webpage. But when I access each name by foreach like above, I cannot see it appear on webpage

Comment: Then the problem is probably not in the code you posted.

Comment: I just tried to write string compnyName to file and I see that it only write the first name to file, and it writes it twice.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest option would be to use LINQ, e.g.

```
var names = companies.Select(c => c.compnName);
```

Comment: it is not under foreach isn't it ? Will names then be an array ? How to access one name, one by one?

Comment: That will produce an enumerable list, i.e. one you can run a `foreach` loop over.  You can call `ToArray` on that to create a `string` array.  You can then get a single name by index from that array.  If you only want one name in the first place then you could call `First`, `Single`, `FirstOrDefault` or `SingleOrDefault` as appropriate before or after `Select`.

Comment: where should I put this and how the foreach and toarray be used in my case? Can you apply that to my code ?

Comment: Just like any code, you put it where you need it.  As I have already said, that code will produce an enumerable list of names.  Where do you need such a list?  That's where you put the code.  As for the `ToArray` call, you would simply tack it onto the end, so you're calling `ToArray` on the result of `Select`.

Comment: The list companies doesn't contain "select" definition. It only have  "Contains"

Comment: `Select` is an extension method.  If you're targeting .NET 3.5 or later then you can reference System.Core.dll, import the `System.Linq` namespace and then call `Select` on anything that implements the `IEnumerable<T>` interface.

Comment: Ok, now I can use .Select: var names = companies.Select(c => c.compnName);  for (int i = 0; i < names.ToArray().Length; i++ ) { string compnyName = names.ToArray()[i]; then I write this compnyName to a file and I see after the for loop, only the first name is written twice. While when I databind() companies to show it on webpage, I see many different names in compnName. Why is that so? What is wrong here ?

Comment: Don't call `ToArray` over and over like that.  Call it once to create a single array, then loop over that array, preferably with a `foreach` loop.